# Is the following a GLM?

Tags: self-study, generalized-linear-model, linear-model, definition, link-function

We know that the standard linear model is a partial case of the GLM scenario by taking the identity link function, i.e.

$$g(μ)=μ=η=x_i^Tβ$$

However, in one of our past papers we are asked to consider the case where we have the case
$$μ=\frac{\beta_0 x}{\beta_1+x}$$
and to say whether this falls under the definition of a GLM and to give the corresponding link function.

**My attempt:** I don't think this can be translated into a GLM, the reason being that we can't find functions $g(.),h_0(.)$ and $h_1(.)$ such that
$g(μ)=β_0h_1(x)+β_1h_2(x)$
as the conditions above are equivalent to
$μβ_1=β_0x−μx$
and we should always have a term that depends on both $μ$ and $β_1$ whereas in a GLM setting the RHS depends only on $\beta$, while the LHS - only on $\mu$.

As far as the inclusions of the functions $h_1$ and $h_2$ - I assumed that each $\eta_i$ has to be linear in the parameters $β_0$ and $\beta_1$ as we've already observed the values of $x_i$, is that not the case? Alternatively, the inclusion of such functions is equivalent to it being a GLM with transformed predictors.

Cheers!

Comment: Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its 
[wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Comment: Where are $h_1$ and $h_2$ coming from? GLMs are of the form $g(\hat{\mu})=\text{linear combination of predictors}$. Do you mean some kind of nonlinear feature space?

Comment: Added the tag. As far as the functions $h_1$ and $h_2$ - I assumed that each $\eta_i$ has to be linear in the parameters $\beta_0$ and $\beta_1$ as we've already observed the values of $x_i$, is that not the case? Alternatively, the inclusion of such functions is equivalent to it being a GLM with transformed predictors.

Comment: Before you worry about figuring out the appropriate link function, determine if this is a linear model. All G***L***M's are linear models.

Comment: @gung-ReinstateMonica So if I understand correctly, the (vague) argument with 'can't separate $\mu$ and $\beta_1$ so that we make it into a linear model' is correct? Thanks!

Comment: These could be a *generalized nonlinear model*. There is an R package `gnm` for such models.